# How do I order results based on a child set of results in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

Given that I have the following object:

```
{
    "bands": [{
        "name": "The Wibbles",
        "formed": 1992,
        "albums": [{
            "name": "A New Wibble",
            "songs": [{
                "name": "Song One",
                "time": "3:12"
            }, {
                "name": "Song Two",
                "time": "2:34"
            }, {
                "name": "Song Three",
                "time": "2:21"
            }, {
                "name": "Song Four",
                "time": "3:44"
            }, {
                "name": "Song Five",
                "time": "3:54"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "The Wibbles Strike Back",
            "songs": [{
                "name": "Song Six",
                "time": "8:12"
            }, {
                "name": "Song Seven",
                "time": "7:34"
            }, {
                "name": "I Killed a Girl",
                "time": "8:21"
            }, {
                "name": "Monkey Fighters",
                "time": "7:44"
            }, {
                "name": "Funkallica",
                "time": "9:54"
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Using AngularJS (and potentially underscore.js), how would I order albums by the shortest track, total album length, or by the shortest average length of the albums tracks?

If I was to then add another band, how would I order the bands themselves by these filters (shortest track / album length / average track length)?

Comment: Custom `orderBy` functions, the `orderBy` clause can take an array `ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy: [myFunc1, myFunc2, ...]`

Comment: Care to write an answer so I can give you actual reputation?

Comment: See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting number strings is kind of a pain, but we can still tackle it. Here is an example given the following html:

```html
<div ng-repeat="band in bands">
  <h1>{{ band.name }}</h1>
  <div ng-repeat="album in band.albums">
    <h2>{{ album.name }}</h2>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="songs in album.songs">
        <h3>{{ song.name }}</h3>
        <em>{{ song.time }}</em>
      </li>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, to order the albums by shortest track:

```html
<div ng-repeat="band in bands">
  <h1>{{ band.name }}</h1>
  <div ng-repeat="album in band.albums | orderBy:shortestTrackByAlbum">
    <h2>{{ album.name }}</h2>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="song in album.songs">
        <h3>{{ song.name }}</h3>
        <em>{{ song.time }}</em>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, in order to perform a custom `orderBy` we need to pass the function (NOT the result of the function) on the current `Scope` that will be used to return the value that is being sorted; in this case `orderBy:shortestTrackByAlbum'.

```js
$scope.bands = [...];
$scope.shortestTrackByAlbum = function(album) {
  var times = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < album.songs.length; i++) {
    var minutesAndSeconds = album.songs[i].split(':'),
        m = parseInt(minutesAndSeconds[0], 10),
        s = parseInt(minutesAndSeconds[1], 10);
    times.push(m * 60 + s);
  }
  return Math.min.apply(null, times);
};
```

Given the data you provided, I converted your times to seconds to find out the smallest number of seconds among the tracks. This *smallest number* is then compared with the other albums' *smallest number* to sort all of these **smallest numbers** (forgive the redundancy).

Using this pattern, you should be able to write a function for each type of situation. See this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zHBeaba0Jz03O8vrkXQY?p=preview) for a simple example.

In addition: if you want the user to be able to change the sorting you could implement something like the following:

```html
<select ng-model="sortingMethod"
        ng-options="m.fn as m.name for m in methods"></select>

...
  <div ng-repeat="album in albums | orderBy:sortingMethod">
...
```

```js
$scope.methods = [
  {
    name: 'Shortest Track',
    fn: $scope.shortestTrackByAlbum
  },
  {
    name: 'Total Album Length',
    fn: $scope.totalAlbumLengthByAlbum
  },
  {
    name: 'Shortest Average Length',
    fn: $scope.shortestAverageLengthByAlbum
  }
];

$scope.shortestTrackByAlbum = function(album) { ... };
$scope.totalAlbumLengthByAlbum = function(album) { ... };
$scope.shortestAverageLengthByAlbum = function(album) { ... };
```

Be sure and check out the docs on [Angular Filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter) and more specifically [Angular's OrderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy).

Comment: Absolutely fantastic, I'm always learning, I was reading the Angular docs and couldn't figure out how to solve my problem before I posted my question, the actual use-case I have is a lot more complicated than this one but I figured that learning how to do a simple version of what I want to do, I can figure the rest myself, the last bit about changing the sorting actually covered something I was going to do next too so thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks, @AndrewWillis, and no problem! Simple-first is typically the best way to go. Good luck!

Comment: I ended up re-writing my back-end API to return the data in a better format, like you said, simple is the best way to go!

Comment: That definitely makes managing the front-end sorting and filter much easier!